# Mixed Content Errors w/ Cloudflare

Tags: joomla-3.x, ssl, https

I'm having some trouble with a couple of sites with mixed content and ssl from Cloudflare. Normally all I need to do is install the plugin from SimBunch and then setup all of my redirects from http to https, but for some reason a few of my sites are having major difficulty with this process.

**Website in Question: https://www.ashleyrowlett.com**

I have tried absolutely everything I can think of and every suggestion I've found in forums. livesite is set to https version in the configuration file, but there are TONS of files still loading the http version causing the mixed content. Caches are all turned off and cleared - I've searched my template for any http references and found nothing. I've tried switching templates to the default Joomla templates to test, same results.

Hosting company can't help me. Cloudflare can't help me. Simbunch can't help me. Not sure where else to go or to try.

Does ANYONE have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**Referenced things I've tried:**

- https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-administration/1506-dealing-with-ssl-mixed-content-in-joomla
- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203624920-How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-in-Joomla-after-enabling-free-Universal-SSL-
- https://www.simbunch.com/products/free-extensions/cloudflare-for-joomla

Comment: In the linked website - your base href is `http://www.ashleyrowlett.com` - and all assets files (css/js etc) seem to be loaded from http - so it looks like Joomla is still under http. Are you sure you have forced the site to load under https?

Comment: Yes - I have live site set as public $live_site = 'https://www.ashleyrowlett.com'; but it has no effect on the base url.

Answer (score 2):

Your baseUrl points to the insecure version, so your sites base href does too.

You can set the correct secure version in your configuration.php file:

```
public $live_site = 'https://www.ashleyrowlett.com';
```

Comment: That's what I currently have set at the moment for the site, but it has no effect at all on the urls and I can't understand why.

Comment: You're looking at cached pages?

Comment: That's possible, but they seem to be cached everywhere and I've cleared browser caches, CloudFlare caches, Joomla caches and disabled any caching that I can find anywhere as mentioned in my original posting. Not sure where else it could be cached.

Comment: If my answer helped then perhaps you can mark it as correct?